# How to include multiple .c files in a single android.mk file?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have 2 .c files hello.c and world.c I'm using ndk-build. I see that the .so file name is actually the name of the "LOCAL_MODULE".
How would I include both the files as a part of the build?

Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c / world.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm getting the below error when I try to access methods in either of the c file.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip 
file.......] couldn't find "libhello.so" at 
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1067)
```

Not sure how I should approach this issue.

Comment: Not sure why you put a `/` between the filenames(?). Have you tried with just `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c world.c` ?

Comment: Also, it looks like you tried to do `System.loadLibrary("hello");`, when you should be doing `System.loadLibrary("test");`.

Comment: Thought / was a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael.

 `init {
  System.loadLibrary("test")
 }
external fun getDemoValue(): String`

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you have two .c files named native and static,
the structure of the cmakelist.txt file will look like this**

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native 
 library.

  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

 # Declares and names the project.

 project("native")

 # Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
 # or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code. 
 # You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
  # Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

 add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    native

    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED

    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).

    native.cpp)




    add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    static

    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED

    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).

    static.cpp)





 # Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
  # variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
 # default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
  # you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
  # completing its b uild.

 find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
    log-lib

    # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
    # you want CMake to locate.
    log)

  # Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
  # can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
  # build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

  target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
    native
    static
    # Links the target library to the log library
    # included in the NDK.
    ${log-lib})
```